# The updated entity is not reflected in database using infinispan EmbaddedCache

Tags: hibernate, infinispan, hibernate-ogm

Issue:
The updated entity is not reflected in database using infinispan EmbaddedCache:
Scenario:

Infinispan version : 8.1
JDK 8

Created TestEntity class with id, name property, configured OGM using persistence.xml, configured jpa-store in infinispan-config.xml.
Infinispan cache is loaded data from database and persist the entity in database whenever call the cache.put(..). The code is follows.

persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">

        <persistence-unit name="ogm-jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                          value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform" />
                <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"
                          value="infinispan" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

        <persistence-unit name="CachePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <class>org.infinispan.persistence.jpa.impl.MetadataEntity</class>
            <!-- <class>com.scb.hws.entity.TlPymtDetails</class> -->
            <properties>
                             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="..."/>
                             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="..."/>
                             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="..."/>
                             <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
                             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                             <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
                    </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>


infinispan-config.xml:
<local-cache name="default">
  <persistence passivation="false">
                <jpa-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:jpa:8.0"
                                                  shared="true" preload="true"
                                                  persistence-unit="CachePersistenceUnit"
                                                  entity-class="TestEntity"
                                                  singleton="false"
                                                  batch-size="1">
                  </jpa-store>
  </persistence>
</local-cache>
```

Whenever persist entity from OGM, the data is reflected in infinispan cache but not reflected in database. How to solve the issue?

Comment: Why exactly do you have two persistence units in persistence.xml? Could you attach a minimalistic code example?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-infinispan-configuration), you need to provide the `hibernate.ogm.infinispan.cachemanager_jndi_name` configuration property:

> If you have an Infinispan EmbeddedCacheManager registered in JNDI,
>   provide the JNDI name and Hibernate OGM will use this instance instead
>   of starting a new CacheManager. This will ignore any further
>   configuration properties as Infinispan is assumed being already
>   configured. Infinispan can typically be pushed to JNDI via WildFly,
>   Spring or Seam.

Comment: I am not sure if Sats wants to really use second level caching, it seems like he wants OGM to be the one who accesses Infinispan, and write to DB using JPA store (therefore, have another Hibernate under Infinispan).